# What do the little icons next to the each variable denote, in the SSIS variables window

Tags: user-interface, ssis, icons, bids

There seems to be variations of the icon image, and I'm sure they mean something. The standard appears to be a blue box with an X in italics. And, some have a little 'circle' in the bottom left of the standard icon image. I have seen a blue circle with an plus in it, a red circle with a plus in it.

What do these mean, and what are the other variations and their meanings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Visual Studio snapin for ETL development that is causing the icons to get an overlay image. I know of two products that do that. I am not familiar with the glyphs you are referencing but they generally indicate an item configured using expressions or

Below is [BIXpress](http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/Business-Intelligence/BIxPress/Default.aspx)

[image: BIXpress from PragmaticWorks]

BIDSHelper (free) calls them [SSIS Variable Window Extensions](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Variables%20Window%20Extensions)

[image: BIDSHelper variables window]

Finally, SQL Denali aka SQL Server v.Next will have "[Icon marker (“Adorner”) to indicate Connection Managers and Variables with expressions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2011/07/12/ssis-what-s-new-in-sql-server-denali.aspx)" (Look really hard and you will see a little fx symbol in the corner of InputFile connection manager)

[image]

Comment: thanks, BIXpress is installed and that is what is overlaying the icons.